# Possible to have a frame index of 1, but not 0?

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs, frames

I am using `phantomjs` and somehow I am ended up with a frame at index position `1` but nothing at index `0`.

I can't reproduce it on my local machine without using phantomjs..

Any ideas? Is this even possible in `html`?

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue, then what's the problem?

Comment: How about adding your code? Edit your question and hit CTRL+ M and paste ALL of your html, css, etc code into the box.

Comment: I can't reproduce it _without_ using phantomjs.

Comment: @AdamThompson ok, but can you reproduce it with phantomjs?

Comment: @a-bobkov yes, on that page.

Comment: @AdamThompson Then we need you code - how to reproduce it with phantomjs. Could you make available for us the html and javascript?